# on the lexicographic order on $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-numbers, order-theory, real-numbers, ordered-fields

I know that the lexicographic order on $\mathbb{C}$ turns it into an ordered set. I just wonder if under this ordering, $\mathbb{C}$ has the least upper bound property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The set
$$\{ z \in \mathbb{C} : \Re z < 0 \}$$
is bounded above by $1$, and has no supremum.